# How can I collapse and expand each specific part of the accordion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion

### AngularJs Accordion Flow

I am having a difficult time grasping the concept of manipulating accordions
I have a step by step module implemented as an accordion. After completion of part 1 of the module, I would like to collapse part 1 and expand part 2. Once part 2 of the module is complete, I want to collapse part 2 and expand part 3
The accordion I am using is as follow:
https://jsfiddle.net/b0yc246z/

```
<div ng-init="accordion=1">
<h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion==1}">
    <a href ng-click="accordion = 1">Section 1</a>
</h3>
<p class="accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==1">Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
    
<h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion==2}">
    <a href ng-click="accordion = 2">Section 2</a>
</h3>
<p class="accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==2">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
    
<h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion==3}">
    <a href ng-click="accordion = 3">Section 3</a>
</h3>
<p class="accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==3">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
```

My initial approach was to give each part of the module and id and manipulate each part through JS
How can I collapse and expand each specific part of the accordion?

Comment: can you explain more the completion aspect mentioned in your question ?

Comment: You expand a specific part of the accordian by clicking on the `<h3>` of the desired part. The other parts will automatically collapse.

Comment: I have an accordion
Each piece of the accordion represents a task and each piece has a button labeled continue 
Initially the first piece will be expanded and once the user hits continue, the first piece will collapse and the 2nd piece will expands and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MSclavi/e9vhs0jL/1/

You can use the same idea but with a button inside the accordion. If you have to do something extra (data verification, etc), you can call a function from the buttons `ng-click`.